# Waffle Web Application SSO Authentication

Tags: java, spring, ldap, single-sign-on, waffle

I have requirement to implement SSO Authentication and validate user with LDAP / AD server in our web application. The web application is made using **Spring (Java) / Hibernate** and application server is **Jboss** in UAT and **Websphere** in Production.

I am searching for some good and easy solution that can help me to implement it and heard from couple of friends **Waffle** is good solution, however after searching on net and trying since past few days am unsure if I am heading in right direction. I am naive in this area, so asking some basic questions to the masters here.

**1.** Can Waffle help in this case? I mean, I got confused as couple of links that I read said that Waffle only helps in Java based application, but not Web application.

**2.** If answer to above is Yes, is there some example that I can refer to? I am not sure how to pass identity information from client to server and then validate it with the LDAP / AD.

**3.** If answer to point 1 is No, any other solution that you can recommend?

Thanks a lot in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, Waffle can help in this case; it can be used for web applications, see for example here:

https://github.com/Waffle/waffle/blob/master/Docs/tomcat/TomcatSingleSignOnValve.md

Waffle is useful for this reason: "(it) allows users to browse to a Windows intranet site without having to re-enter credentials"

Waffle seems to fit your requirements. It works with various versions of Tomcat application server.

2. from the same link before, see Waffle Authenticator Demo

Comment: Thank you @mrtexaz, While I started implementing the created NegotiateSecurityFilterProvider and other configuration as suggested in Waffle documentation, however I am not getting any information from the browser in the request. I mean the Security Package or Authorization header. Any clue, what I might be doing wrong or is there any setup that needs to be done in Browser end to pass such information? Thanks :)

Comment: what browser are you using? I would try Internet Explorer with the pc being part of a windows domain. But it would be best to see all the log files, to undestand the issue. Set waffle.apache.NegotiateAuthenticator.level = FINE in tomcat configuration.